# Unable to resolve ADC conversion error in stm8s105s6

Tags: embedded, st-link, stm8

I'm trying to learn ADC on `stm8s105s6`. But not getting proper adc result. I shorted VCC to analog pin 3 and expected conversion value near 1023 as stm8 has a  10 bit adc.

```
#include "stm8s105s6.h"
unsigned int a=0;
main()
{
        CLK_CKDIVR=0x00;

        FLASH_DUKR = 0XAE;
        FLASH_DUKR = 0X56;


     //WAP to read ADC Data.



        ADC_CSR                 =0B00000011;// channel 3, ADC not complete
        ADC_CR1                 =0B00100010;// F/4 , continous converion disable adc
        ADC_CR2                 =0B00000000;// Left Align
        ADC_CR3                 =0B00000000;// Data Buffer Disable
        ADC_TDRH                =0B00000000;// Schmitt Trigger Enabled
        ADC_TDRL                =0B00001000;// Schmitt Trigger Enabled
        ADC_CR1                |=0B00000001;// Enable ADC 

        while(1)
        {
            ADC_CR1|=0B00000001;//Enable ADC
            while((ADC_CSR&0x80)==0x00);//Till EOC is reached.
            ADC_CSR&=0B01111111;//Not Completed

            a=ADC_DRH;
            a=a<<2;
            a=a | ADC_DRL;
            delay_s(1);
        }
}
```

Comment: Is there a VREF you must bias?

Answer (score 0):

Your shifts look suspect. I think you want right, not left, align, and then

a = (ADC_DRH << 8) | ADC_DRL;